# How can Implement OpenID Feature in ASP NET2.0

Tags: asp.net, openid

How can I implement `OpenID` feature in ASP NET2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some .NET options here: http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an RPX http://rpxnow.com .   The service will allow you to accept OpenIDs, Facebook, and MySpace .   Your application needs to be able to make https calls out, and be able to parse xml or json responses.